# Scala monad with flatMap definition

Tags: scala

I have a construct, let's call it Container. It, as you might guess, is a container for another object, with some headers (a simple map). There are two instances of the container, a success container, or a failed container.

I have a function defined on container, called

`flatMap(f: Container[T]=> Container[U]): Container[U]`

Pretty familiar right, except unlike a 'real' monad, it's from M[A]->M[B], rather than A->M[B]. This is because I want the mapping functions to have access to all the fields of the container.

Now there's no real problem with this, except it doesn't follow the definitions for a monad and so it doesn't work with for comprehensions as a generator.

Any suggestions, other than changing the flatMap definition, or am I just SoL :)

Comment: There's no *real* monad and *not real* monad.  It either is, or it is not

Comment: Presumably the function passed as `f` **already** has access to other members of `Container`.  After all... you must already have started with an instance in order to be able to invoke `flatMap` in the first place!

Comment: Not sure what you mean Kevin, because if the flatMap was defined as T => Container[U] as you'd normally expect, then the function would be getting a T and not a Container[T] and wouldn't have access to the extra fluff that the container object provides.

Comment: If I invoke `xs.flatMap(transform(_))`, then **I have the instance `xs`** - This could easily be passed if `transform` was differently defined, as in `xs.flatMap(otherTransform(xs)(_))`.  Voila, the mapping function now knows about the container!

Comment: Right I see. Fiddle it, so the arg from the flatMap itself is basically irrelevant, because you're going to access the monad as a free variable. Clever.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If `Container` was a collection then you'd still want to act on each element, you'd just have the whole collection available as well, for whatever reason.

Comment: Right, yes. In my case tho, since Container is for a single element (I did not make that clear in my post, but its essentially a wrapper around an element), the arg would be superfluous. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going from `M[A]` to `M[B]` then all you want is `map`

```
class Container[A](stuff: A){
  def map[B](f: A => B): Container[B] = new Container(f(stuff))
}
```

The function `flatMap` really is for functions of type `A => M[B]` to be able to work on a type of `M[A]`. Hence,

```
 class Container[A](stuff: A){
   def map[B](f: A => B): Container[B] = new Container(f(stuff))

   def flatMap[B](f: A => Contains[B]): Container[B] = f(stuff)
 }
```

so you really don't need `flatMap` in your definition at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand. That function is not very useful, in my real world project, because `stuff` here is only one of the fields, and the functions people will pass in would need access to all the fields. I guess I could make the arg a tuple, but that's blah.

Comment: @monkjack is it more that you have `M[A, B, C, D] => M[E, F, G, H]`? Then you don't really want a `map` or `flatMap`. Those really are defined for only a single value.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I guess what I have is some pseudo monadic container of a container, except I've combined them together.